# Group headers are not visible when hiding/show any column

Tags: jqgrid

I am implementing show hide column feature and grouping the headers at a time. 
on load able to see all headers nicely. if i hide any column all group headers are gone. when i am showing that column it is not retreiving back. please help to resolve this issue.

```
jQuery("#navgrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: false, 
            groupHeaders:[
                {startColumnName: 'srno', numberOfColumns: 16, titleText: "Annexure"}
            ]
        });
        jQuery("#navgrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: false, 
            groupHeaders:[
                {startColumnName: 'srno', numberOfColumns: 10, titleText: "Annexure"}
            ]
        });

grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth",1280,true);
$("#hc2").prop('value', 'Show 405 to 409 columns');
for(var i=5;i<=9;i++)
{grid.jqGrid('hideCol',grid.getGridParam("colModel")[i].name);}
```